# Calculating order price with javascript based on picklist value and variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to calculate total order price from the following:

number of a specific item determined by a picklist value * set cost for that item

there are 3 items total and this is what my calculation looks like right now but don't work (nothing happens when I click the button):

```
function calculate();
{

        var mugPrice = 5;
        var keyringPrice = 2;
        var tshirtPrice = 15;

        var numMug = document.getElementById('numberOfMugs').value
        var numTshirt = document.getElementById('numberOfTshirts').value
        var numKeyring = document.getElementById('numberOfKeyrings').value

        var totalpay = (numMug * mugPrice) + (numTshirt * tshirtPrice) + (numKeyring * keyringPrice);

        document.getElementById('totalPrice').value= totalpay;      
}
```

and this is what my button and field look like:

```
<button class="calcButton" onclick="calculate()">Calculate Order</button>
<h3>Total price: <input type=text; id="totalPrice" disabled /> </h3>
```

numMug, numTshirt and numKeyring are the id's of the picklists which have values corresponding to the number of items someone wishes to purchase

not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: @NinaScholz nothing happens when I click the button

Comment: remove the `;` from the function declaration: `function calculate();` the correct is without the `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the semicolon:

```
function calculate();
                    ^
```

```js
'use strict';
function calculate() {
    var mugPrice = 5,
        keyringPrice = 2,
        tshirtPrice = 15,
        numMug = +document.getElementById('numberOfMugs').value || 0,
        numTshirt = +document.getElementById('numberOfTshirts').value || 0,
        numKeyring = +document.getElementById('numberOfKeyrings').value || 0,
        totalpay = (numMug * mugPrice) + (numTshirt * tshirtPrice) + (numKeyring * keyringPrice);

    document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = totalpay;
}
```

```html
Mugs: <input type="input" id="numberOfMugs"><br>
T-Shirts: <input type="input" id="numberOfTshirts"><br>
Keyrings: <input type="input" id="numberOfKeyrings"><br>

<button type="button" class="calcButton" onclick="calculate()">Calculate Order</button>
<h3>Total price: <input type="text" id="totalPrice" disabled /></h3>
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, that seems to work, however the value is visible for a split second and then the box goes blank again, any idea why?

Comment: the button works as submit, you need to prevent to state the type of the button with `type="button"`.